# Differential equation $y'=(1+f^{2}(x))y(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Differential equation $$y'=(1+f^{2}(x))y(x), y(0)=1,x\geq0$$ where $f$ is a bounded continuous function on $[0,\infty).$  Prove that the given ODE has unique solution $y$ and $y\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$ Uniqueness is clear as $f$ is given to be bounded and hence $g(x,y)=(1+f^{2}(x))y(x)$ is Lipschitz . It remains to prove that $y\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$ If i take some particular function say $f=0$ then the result is true. But i like some general concept from analysis to show that $y\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$ Please help me to prove this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing both sides by y(x)  and integrating gives you :

$\int \frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{y(x)} dx\ = \int (f^2(x) + 1)dx $

Solving that gets you : $ ln(y(x)) = \int (f^2(x) + 1) dx + c_1 $

Finally, the solution of your ODE is :  $ y(x) = c_1e^{\int(f^2(x) +1)dx} $

You then, can work out the solution to your question from this.

Comment: It comes as $y=c(e^{x}e^{\int f^{2}})$ how it tends to $\infty$??

Comment: Given from the definitions of the exercise you can easily find it out, also as a hint : Show that y=0 is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but if your function $y$ is a function of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the solutoin of the equation is $$y(x)=\exp^{\int^{x}_{0}1+f^2(t)dt}$$
and this is greater than $\exp(x)$. You can use comparison as well, saying that $$z_1'\leqslant (1+C)z_1$$ where $C\geqslant f^2$ and $$z_2'\geqslant z_2$$ and compare $y$ with  the two solutions of these ODE.